# OpenAPI compile generated client

Tags: maven, openapi, openapi-generator

I am generating client with openapi-generator-maven-plugin

```
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <configOptions>
                                <java8>true</java8>
                                <library>jersey2</library>
                                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                                <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
                                <artifactVersion>${version}</artifactVersion>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <modelPackage>com.jw.model</modelPackage>
                                <apiPackage>com.jw.api</apiPackage>
                                <invokerPackage>com.jw</invokerPackage>
                                <parentArtifactId>${project.parent.artifactId}</parentArtifactId>
                                <parentGroupId>${project.parent.groupId}</parentGroupId>
                                <parentVersion>${project.parent.version}</parentVersion>
                            </configOptions>
                            <addCompileSourceRoot>false</addCompileSourceRoot>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/openapi/client</output>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```

After I am trying to `mvn install` inside `target` in `openapi/client`. but the `classes` folder is not generated, although in `src` classes successfully generated.

On the image result after `mvn install`. And there for some reason 2 JARs:

[image: result of mvn install]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the relevant part(s) of the build output to your question, e.g. `compiler-plugin`. For the `*-test,jar` see [`jar:test-jar`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html) which most probably is configured in parts of your POM you don't show us.